# Create table in Word Document From Access using VBA

Tags: ms-access, ms-word, vba

I am trying to create tables in a Word document template from my Access database.

This bit of code runs fine from Word itself and creates tables as required. I was wondering if its possible to run this code from Access and point to a specific word document in which to create the tables.

```
Dim numberOfTables As Integer
Dim iCount As Integer

numberOfTables = InputBox("How many tables to make?", "Tables")

For iCount = 0 To numberOfTables - 1

    ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=2, NumColumns:= _
        3, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:= _
        wdAutoFitFixed
    With Selection.Tables(1)
        If .Style <> "Table Grid" Then
            .Style = "Table Grid"
        End If
        .ApplyStyleHeadingRows = True
        .ApplyStyleLastRow = False
        .ApplyStyleFirstColumn = True
        .ApplyStyleLastColumn = False
        '.ApplyStyleRowBands = True 'Office 2010
        '.ApplyStyleColumnBands = False 'Office 2007
    End With

    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
    Selection.TypeParagraph

Next iCount
```

Comment: You need to ask yourself how `ActiveDocument` and `Selection` can be worked out from the outside. Are you referencing the Word object model?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But you need to know: 1) Do you assume Word is already running? 2) Do you assume the target document is already open? 3) If the document is not open, how to find the file(path) to the document to open it? 4) And once the document is open, how to find where the table should be inserted? We can't help you without complete information...

Comment: 1) Word is not already running. 2) The target document is not already open. 3) The filepath will be on my C drive eg. C:\database\template.docx. 4) I was under the assumption that the range object could be used to set where the table should be inserted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is to first open a new instance of Word from Access. This is done by the following command:

```
Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
```

Then to make it visible and to add a document, you use this object from that point on:

```
wrdApp.Visible = True
Set myDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Add   'Here you should also keep the new document as an object so you can directly refer to it
```

Or if you use a template you need to open it instead:

```
wrdApp.Visible = True
Set myDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open ("C:\database\template.docx")
```

And then comes your code that you need to modify accordingly to the above:

```
For iCount = 0 To numberOfTables - 1

    myDoc.Tables.Add Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=2, NumColumns:= _
        3, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:= _
        wdAutoFitFixed
    With myDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Tables(1)  
'Note here that for the Selection object you need to refer to the active window
        If .Style <> "Table Grid" Then
            .Style = "Table Grid"
        End If
        .ApplyStyleHeadingRows = True
        .ApplyStyleLastRow = False
        .ApplyStyleFirstColumn = True
        .ApplyStyleLastColumn = False
        '.ApplyStyleRowBands = True 'Office 2010
        '.ApplyStyleColumnBands = False 'Office 2007
    End With

    myDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
    myDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.TypeParagraph

Next iCount
```

This should get you started.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. That seems to be exactly what I was looking for however the document will already be stored in a folder with filepath eg. C:\database\template.docx

Comment: In that case you need to use `Set myDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open` Then you want to `myDoc.SaveAs` so as not to overwrite the template.

Comment: I get an error on the second line ` myDoc.Tables.Add Range...` Runtime error 424 object required. I am unsure what I am missing

Comment: You need to add your document after the Open, like: `Set myDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open ("C:\database\template.docx")`

Comment: @mekzek I updated the answer with the code of opening a template.