# word MailMerge (from MS Access data source) dynamic table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, mailmerge, docx-mailmerge

Mailmerge with Dynamic Table
Hi there
I have a long list of data in an Ms access which I need to mailmerge into letters to send to recipients.

[data source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmU6D.jpg)

The challenge I am facing is that I need it to send only one email per unique "Name", but for the email to present a dynamic table which lists all of the devices, alongside their number. The number of devices per person varies. For example, my dream output from the data above would be two emails: one to Joe Bloggs, and one to John Smith, with the following text:

**
Hi Joe Bloggs
I have noticed you have the following devices registered to your name:

[from the data source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVGqA.png)

Please let me know if you still need these devices and if not, I will switch them off.
Thanks,
Joe.

Comment: I wouldn't bother with Word merge. I would just build the email with Access VBA. A simple concatenation of data from recordset can be sent with SendObject. Or use Outlook automation and build an HTML formatted table.

Comment: Soory the original idea was to send email, but now we want to generate documents.

Comment: I would probably still find a way to build in Access. I think building table in Word would require Word automation code, not simple merge. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37006698/create-table-in-word-document-from-access-using-vba